# nested if loop partially working

Tags: php, html, mysql

What I am trying to do is simply display the row values. Now suppose if the field 'head_office' dont have the value 'H.O' then I want to display the values of the last row. I tried but cant find any solution. Here is my code: (I have only blocked the php part)

```
 <?php
 $mysql_host = 'localhost';
 $mysql_user = 'root';
 $mysql_password = '123';
 $mysql_database = 'sdbms';
 $setup_page = './myinstitute.php';
 $db = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
 mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db);


 if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM institute WHERE id =$id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 }
 else if(!isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM institute WHERE head_office ="H.O"';
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 }
 else{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM institute";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    $n = mysql_num_rows($result); //counting number of rows
    if($n==0){
        header('Location: '.$setup_page);
    }
    else{
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM institute ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }
 }

?>
```

Comment: Obligatory this is prone to SQL injection and thus very insecure.

Comment: Where is your while loop? **obligatory** please upgrade to the `mysqli_` or `PDO` methods for handling the database - `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Comment: sidenote: to simplify the code you can write single mysql_query and mysql fetch at the end of the code instead of writing it in each block

Comment: How will your code ever get to after the second "else"? Either $_REQUEST['id'] is set or not, so one of those branches is executed, none of those below.

Comment: You very first IF and ESLE IF negates each other therefore the ELSE part will never ever execute. IF happy==true {} ELSE IF happy==false{} ELSE {}. Happy can either be true or false.

Comment: in that case should i remove the 2nd block?

I want to do the following steps:
1. Check whether any link is clicked hence carrying the row id. If so then am fetchn d data and displaying in the body.
2. If no link is clicked then it will fetch the data of the row that has a field value 'H.O' and display it the same way.
3. If none of the above condition is fulfilled then it will check whether the table has any row and he not then it will be re-directed to a setup page but if there is a row but that row doesn't have a field with the value 'H.O' then it will fetch the data of the last row in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand very well how do you want to do, but it's illogic: the three step don't execute ever. Try it:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM institute WHERE id =$id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
else if(!isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM institute WHERE head_office ="H.O"';
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
if(count($row)<=0) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM institute";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    $n = mysql_num_rows($result); //counting number of rows
    if($n==0){
        header('Location: '.$setup_page);
    }
    else{
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM institute ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }
}
```

Enjoy your code.

Comment: Exactly that is the thing. It doesnt execute from the third if. Is there any hint I could use to execute the conditions and also protect it from sql injection?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_password = '123';
$mysql_database = 'sdbms';
$setup_page = './myinstitute.php';
$db = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db);
$row = array();


if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
    $id = (int) $_REQUEST['id'];
    if(!empty($id)) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM institute WHERE id =$id";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }
} else {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM institute WHERE head_office = "H.O"';
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

if(!isset($_REQUEST['id']) && empty($row))
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM institute";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    $n = mysql_num_rows($result); //counting number of rows

    if($n == 0) {
        header('Location: ' . $setup_page);
    } else {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM institute ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This seems to be what OP was looking for, but still doesn't address the injection vulnerability so I can't upvote as best solution.

Comment: The else if...is BAD.  Replace it with an else.

Comment: I have got one more query relating to this piece of code. I would like to display a notice to the user that no 'H.O' has been set and continue to display until the user sets a H.O. How can I achieve this?
what I have tried doing is adding

     $notice="please set a head office for your institute!";


in the last else block.

Answer (score 2):

As `$_REQUEST['id']` can only have 2 status, isset and !isset, the else statement will never be used.

Comment: Then should I use GET?

Comment: That would be the same, the isset function will return a boolean, so you can only get a true or false value. Knowing this, your code look like this.
`if (something == true){
 do something  
} else if (something == false){  
 do another thing  
} else {
 do something else
}`
So, as you can see, if something is true, will enter the if, if something is false, will enter the else if. So you will never use the last else code.
To deal with that you should look at the solutions given by Prava or Magicianred.